# How can I get the value of an input in twig and reuse in an url that exists in the same page twig without the use jquery

Tags: twig, symfony4, twig-extension, twig-filter, twig.js

```
<div class="product-btns">
    <div class="qty-input">
        <span class="text-uppercase">QTY: </span>
        <input name="quantite" class="input" type="number">
    </div>

    {% if app.user != null %}

    <a id="test" href="{{path('commande'{'id_product':listProduct.id ,'id_user':app.user.id,'quantite': })}}" class="primary-btn add-to-cart">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        Add to Cart
    </a>
    {% else %}
```

I want to get value of input name="quantite" and reuse in path of parameter 'quantite'.

Comment: I tried to edit your title for readability, so I clicked "requires editing," without realizing it would push that work onto you. I suggest the following: "In twig, without using jquery, how can I get the value of an input and reuse in a url on the same page?"

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried ?

```
{{ form.vars.value.quantite }}
```